# setuptools_scm raises AssertionError: own dev numbers are unsupported

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setuptools-scm

I have been using these two arguments in the setup.py for a while without any problems.

```
use_scm_version={"local_scheme": "no-local-version",},
setup_requires=["setuptools_scm"],
```

Although I have not made any changes on the `setup.py`, today I started having this exception below.

```
AssertionError: own dev numbers are unsupported
```

It happens when I call `python setup.py`.
I suspect it is due to a change the maintainers of setuptools made recently.

The full error goes like this:

```
module_name/.eggs/setuptools_scm-4.1.2-py3.7.egg/setuptools_scm/version.py", line 229, in _bump_dev
    assert tail == "0", "own dev numbers are unsupported"
AssertionError: own dev numbers are unsupported
```

I tried changing the `setup.py` with this

```
use_scm_version=True,
setup_requires=["setuptools_scm"],
```

Still the exception is raised. What might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added a tag that ends with a `.devN` (where `N` is a number)?

Comment: Yes, our CI script added it. That's the issue. I will disable it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you encounter this error, check the git tags with the
`git tag -l` command.

If a tag is containing `dev` in its name such as `0.1.dev37` then delete it using `git tag -d 0.1.dev37`.

Comment: Could you comment on what is supported in git tags? Like, can I tag alpha and beta versions?

Comment: Could you specify how you indicate the alpha and beta versions in a version?